# Module 'firebase' not available on mobile device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I need some help with firebase. I have an app with ionic, angularjs and firebase and works fine with browser. When I deploy to emulator or device I get the below error message.

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I have included the header files as follows

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script  src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js">  </script>

  <!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

Can someone tell me if I missed anything?

Comment: Hi, do you remember what the issue was and how you fixed it? Thanks.